# Trying to change what column this code checks

Tags: php, sql

Simple question. What does this code do?

```
public function claim(Request $request){       
   $comment = Comment::where('key',$request->key)->where('is_deleted','No')->first();      
   if(!empty($comment)){
     return 1;
   }else{
      return 0;
   }
}
```

I've tried changing what keys it's trying to match, but then it breaks.

EDIT:

Based on the answers I've got so far, it sounds like its checking for comments who's key matches the requested one. When I change the code to this, the form stops responding:

```
 public function claim(Request $request){
       
     $user = User::where('key',$request->key)->where('is_deleted','No')->first();
      
       if(!empty($user)){
         return 1;
       }else{
          return 0;
       }
   }
```

EDIT 2:

I have a table called Posts and a table called Users. Each entry on the Post table has a unique ID, a Title, and a Key (B_Key). That Key matches only 1 entry in the Users table. Each User has 3 keys (A_Key, B_Key, C_Key).

I'm trying to make my form ask for A_Key, then check if the User with that A_Key also has the B_Key that was used to publish this specific post. I tried writing a SQL query but have failed. Here is is:

```
$post = "SELECT posts.id, users.A_Key FROM posts INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id=users.A_Key WHERE posts.is_deleted = No";
      
       
       if(!empty($post)){
           return 1;
      
       }
       else{
           return 0;
           
       }
   }
```

Comment: Basically the code currently checks if there are any comments whose key match the requested key and aren't deleted, and if there is (at least) one, it returns 1. If not, it returns 0. So what did you change? What did you expect the change to achieve? What does "breaks" mean - is there an error, or unexpected output, or what? Is your real question how to make the change you're trying to achieve, without a problem occurring? If so, then please explain the problem clearly as I've outlined. Thanks.

Comment: Is the question what does it do, or how to change what it is doing? Sounds like XY question

Comment: Well, I've been making small changes to this code and cannot get it to do what I want, so I posted it here to make sure I understood what it's currently doing. 

Basically I have a users table and each user has 3 id's. This code seems to check if the post matches a column called secondary_key. I need it to check if it matches a column called primary_key.

Comment: `the form stops responding` isn't really an error message or a clear problem statement. What exactly happens when you run the `claim` function? Does it cause a specific exception message or anything?

Comment: `This code seems to check if the post matches a column called secondary_key`...what makes you think that? The code refers to `key`, rather than anything else. `secondary_` isn't mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Re edit 2: `if(!empty($post)){` makes no sense really, because $post is just a SQL string, it's static text and will never be empty. If you're going to use raw SQL instead of your ORM you'd need to actually _execute_ the query and get the result, and then check the number of rows returned.

Comment: `ON posts.id=users.A_Key`...is that the correct join? It's a little unclear without sample data accompanying, but from what you've said is it supposed to be`ON posts.B_Key=users.A_Key`?

Comment: The common value between the Posts table and the Users table will be the B_Key. The post will have the B_Key listed, and of course the user table will have it as well. So I'm trying to have it find a post where these two match based on the input of an A_Key in the form.

Comment: `The common value between the Posts table and the Users table will be the B_Key`...that's what you should JOIN using, then. `based on the input of an A_Key`...you mean you want to also filter on the A_Key field? So maybe something like `SELECT posts.id, users.A_Key FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON posts.B_Key=users.B_Key WHERE posts.is_deleted = No AND users.A_Key = ?` ? Again, it's really difficult to answer SQL questions without sample source data and also an example of the expected result of querying that sample data.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any comment which is related with key and if didn't has then result will return 1 (true) else 0 (false)